# Linq Filter - After Filter Expecting Result Should be Nothing

Tags: vb.net, linq

Please check below code, as my question related to following example.

```
Dim objPOSMaxDiscountTemplateDetailList As POSMaxDiscountTemplateDetailList
objPOSMaxDiscountTemplateDetailList = _
     POSMaxDiscountTemplateDetailList.GetPOSMaxDiscountTemplateDetailList(UserDiscountPolicyTemplateCode)

'Filtering Above List
Dim Data = (From p In objPOSMaxDiscountTemplateDetailList _
                    Where p.ItemTypeCode = ItemTypeCode)

If Data IsNot Nothing Then
   '' Do Something
End If
```

In above example objPOSMaxDiscountTemplateDetailList object am getting 14 records. After that am filtering those record with ItemTypeCode condition and there is no matched record with ItemTypeCode. So I am expecting Data object will be nothing. But while debugging i found Data object is not nothing and data.count am getting 0.

I don't understand this behavior, as same type of coding i made some other class which running perfectly as per my expectation.

Thanks.

Comment: Suppose you initialized a list object like this : Dim myList as New List(of Integer).  The list is initially not Nothing and contains zero integers.  This is what linq is returning when the filter fails to find any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't be `Nothing`. It will be an empty collection. LINQ to Objects query **almost** never returns `Nothing`.

Try

```
If Not Data.Any() Then
   '' Do Something
End If
```

Comment: What mean by almost? At what case, i will get nothing?

Comment: If you e.g. `Enumerable.Repeat("null", 10).First();`, or use `FirstOrDefault/SingleOrDefault` on a collection of reference type that doesn't have any items in it. So queries that return single elements can return `null`. Any query that returns multiple items will return an empty collection instead of `null` when there is nothing to return.

Comment: As I previously return that some of class its working fine, i used 'SingleOrDefault' and hence its returning 'Nothing'. Thanks MarcinJuraszek..!!!